# Ensuring consistency in in-memory data structures

Tags: java, service, concurrency, in-memory, data-consistency

I was wondering what would have been the best way (probably I am looking for a pattern) to ensure data consistency in an everyday example where a service retrieves data by invoking some method on a gateway (the gateway might be the boundary for DB, a web call or even an in-memory data structure).

Here is an example of the case I described in Java:

```
public class MyService {

    private DataSourceGateway dataSourceGateway;

    public MyService(DataSourceGateway dataSourceGateway) {
        this.dataSourceGateway = dataSourceGateway;
    }

    public void myServiceMethod() {
        doThings1();
        doThings2();
    }

    private void doThings1() {
        int count = dataSourceGateway.getCount();
        // do things with this count
    }

    private void doThings2() {
        int count = dataSourceGateway.getCount();
        // do things with this count which is expected to be the same as in doThings1()
    }
}
```

Let's assume that DataSourceGateway might not be a database that offers transactions, but an in-memory data structure and DataSourceGateway and Service are Singletons.

The obvious consistency problem would be when another service modifies the data in DataSourceGateway when a call to `myServiceMethod()` has completed `doThings1()` and is about to execute `doThings2()`.

The example is simplified but consider the cases when not the same method on dataSourceGateway is called but also calls on objects that have some dependencies (e.g. getCount and getAll should be consistent). The reason I called this an everyday problem is because I have seen the same `DataSourceGateway`s (or DAOs) being injected in multiple places and usually the developer expect that the calls would be consistent.

What would be the best way to ensure that count would be the same these 2 calls?

Comment: If the count is expected to be the same, why not pass the count from `doThings1` to `doThings1`?  You could implement some form of transactions for your in memory data store. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Comment: @dm03514  your solution applies in over-simplified example but consider cases where you want to get all the data and later on you want to get the count of the data from the datasource. In that case, you would do 2 different calls with different responses. Or you could even consider the case where 2 different collections of data should be consistent. Even if you retrieve them in the beginning of the service method there is no guarantee of the desired consistency to hold.